# django-mailer error whent trying to send mail

Tags: python, django, django-mailer

I have followed the [installation steps](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer) provided by the repository provider of `django-mailer`

but when I try the `./manage.py test mailer` command

or `./manage.py send_mail` command

I receive this error:

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import quote
ImportError: No module named urllib.parse
```

I receive this error on both my development machine and the production server.

On both I run `Python 2.6`

I already asked under [issues](https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer/issues/20) tracker of `django-mailer` but there was no reply. As I really need to implement this sort of functionality in a few days on a project, this is my last atempt to use this otherwise I will have to come up with another solution.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

BR

Comment: What is your version of six? `import six; six.__version__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `six` version is equal or less than `1.3.0`:

```
In [1]: import six
In [2]: six.__version__
Out[2]: '1.3.0'
In [3]: from six.moves.urllib.parse import quote
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4680c55c65e8> in <module>()
----> 1 from six.moves.urllib.parse import quote

ImportError: No module named urllib.parse
```

try to upgrade `six` by:

```
pip install six --upgrade
```

Then import of `quote` is ok:

```
In [1]: import six

In [2]: six.__version__
Out[2]: '1.5.2'

In [3]: from six.moves.urllib.parse import quote
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this was the problem and you helped me a lot with this.

A BIG thanks again!!